# my PC isn't reacting to the power button & not displaying anything

Tags: boot, power-supply, desktop

i've moved to another house , and today i just plugged in my pc's power cable ,then my pc (HP COMPAQ desktop) turned on as if i pressed the power button) ,but it doesn't show anything on the monitor ,the monitor is working with my other pc, i tried to figure out what the problem is , removing RAM doesn't give me the 2 beeps nor a message on the screen (screen is black all the time) , removing the CPU : the green light on the desktop becomes, a kind of, blue , also removing the HDD turns the green light of hdd activity, to blue, another problem is , when pressing the power button it doesn't shut down the pc ,i can hear all the fans running (including the PSU fan ) so, what should i do now , thanks guys

Comment: Try resetting\Clearing the CMOS. deprive it of power fully for an hour or two, and make sure your CPU fan is running. I had simillar issues a few months ago with a box when the heatsink fan stopped working. that behavior changes from mobo to mobo.

Comment: i'm trying resetting the CMOS , my CPU fan is working perfectly ,i'll try to borrow another cpu to test if it works , thanks for help :D

Comment: In all my years, I've never blown a CPU, but plenty of motherboards, and power supplies. Even when moving, it is very unlikely that your CPU was damaged but that your motherboard or mechanical hard disks were not, so unless you suspect static discharge, I'd guess that a differant CPU is unlikely to work better. Just a hunch based on years of experience.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using another CPU? Maybe one borrowed from a pal? 
Also, I'd try another PSU. Maybe yours for some reason ain't delivering the necessary power to completely boot the machine (I've had this issue)
After all that tried, I'd think the possibility of a fried MB.
Did you try also clearing the CMOS?

Comment: yea, i'm trying clearing the cmos 1st , then i'll try another cpu , wht's the MB , how i can get to know if it's fried ? thanks a lot

Comment: MB = motherboard, the big thing everything else plugs into

Answer (score 0):

Since you just moved, you might want to try reseating (removing and re-inserting) anything that could have come loose in the move, particularly the memory and the video card (if you have a dedicated video card).

Comment: yeaa i tried , resinserting the Ram, cpu, cables, ... thanks ;)